# NestJS problem with GraphQL when I implementing GraphQLModule

Tags: graphql, nestjs

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql',
      playground: true,
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
    }),
  ],

})
export class AppModule {}
```

Hello I have problem that I didn't find any solution for it.
I've created nestjs project ( nest new ) and then I instaled some packages form NestJS documentation ( npm i --save @nestjs/graphql graphql-tools graphql apollo-server-express)
But after add a GraphQLModule to module imports, I get an error.

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625
  throw e;
  ^
Error: No valid exports main found for '/Users/Andrzej/Downloads/WebApps/Testing/becker-app-master-api/api/node_modules/extract-files'

at Object. (/Users/Andrzej/Downloads/WebApps/Testing/becker-app-master-api/api/node_modules/apollo-upload-client/lib/index.js:21:17)

Comment: It is against the SO rules to link something because sometime in the future the link will be broken and your question and the answer will not be understood.

Comment: What do you mean exacly?

Comment: You must put all the information that you linked to inside your question.  Or someone will give you a down arrow because you aren't following the rules.  Most people on SO are very nice and helpful, but there are some who are not.  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched the issues of the package generating the error. To quote https://github.com/jaydenseric/extract-files/issues/13

> This package uses the final Node.js conditional exports API
>
> Node.js v13.0.0 - v13.6 will not work as those versions support package exports but not conditional exports.
>
> Node.js v13.7+ will work fine, and all v10 and v12 versions should work.